# What comes to your mind, or you think this logo represents to you

Tags: logo, branding, identity

[image]

What comes to your mind, or you think this logo represents to you.
what do you think about this logo?

Comment: Asking opinions in style "tell what you see here, or which impression this makes for you" are judged to be reasons to close the question

Comment: Welcome to **GD.SE** - ***please*** look over [tour] to learn about our community; please *also* read ***[ask]*** and [answer] a question to understand *what* makes a good question here, and *how to frame it* to get the best answers and responses. As currently framed, this question falls far short of meeting the standards for critique questions - see [https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/681/what-are-the-guidelines-for-asking-for-a-critique-of-my-work] and so you should edit it to narrow the scope and make it less opinion-only dependent for qualified replies.